# Trouble with cross referencing in the appendices

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, appendices

I'm trying to get the figures and labels in my appendices to have the same format as the rest of the document.  In my main thesis.tex file I use:

```
    \backmatter % book mode only
    \appendix
    \include{Appendix1/appendix1}
```

and then in the appendix1.tex file I have:

```
    \chapter{Appendix A - Data}
    \label{ch:App1}
```

This produces my appendices as I wish, displaying "Appendix A - Data" in the table of contents etc.  However, it also restarts the numbering of figures and tables.  So for example I would have Figures 5.1, 5.2, ... in Chapter 5, presently I have Figures 1, 2, 3, ... in Appendix A, whereas I would rather something along the lines of Figure A.1 etc.  The same applies to Tables.

Also, when I reference the appendix in an earlier chapter using:

```
    Appendix \ref{ch:App1}
```

It is referenced as "Appendix 7" (I have 6 preceding chapters) as opposed to "Appendix A" as listed in the contents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\backmatter` disables numbering of chapters. Remove it and remove also "Appendix A" from the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\backmatter` disables chapter numbering. If you want to number the appendices, put them *before* `\backmatter` (or remove `\backmatter` altogether).

The standard output you get with

```
\appendix
\chapter{Data}
```

is something like

> #### Appendix A
>
> ### Data

so you don't need to add "Appendix A" to your chapter title.